# How to change the font of a cross reference made using \ref

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, footnotes

I am using the Cambridge University Press book class cambridge7A (available at  http://authornet.cambridge.org/information/productionguide/laTex_files/ and much used by CUP authors)

A minimal example both describes and illustrates the problem if you run it:

```
\documentclass{cambridge7a}

\begin{document}

Suppose we introduce a footnote here\footnote{\label{myfootnote} 
And here's the note text!}, and then we later refer want to refer to the note, 
as fn.~\ref{myfootnote}. 

Then the number in the latter cross-reference is superscripted, 
when we of course will want a simple inline reference, like this: fn. 1. 

\end{document}
```

So the question is: preferably without hacking into the class file, is there simple  way of forcing the cross-reference produced \ref{my footnote} to return a number in the normal font (for the context it is occurring in) rather than a superscripted script sized number.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this: `\let\oldref\ref \renewcommand{\ref}{\normalsize\oldref}`

Comment: The class must have made some changes. With a standard class you _would_ get the number inline...

Comment: I wouldn't use footnotes for this. I'd use a bibliography-aware package such as `biblatex` for managing the citations and the references.

Comment: Defining `\thefootnote` as `\mbox{$\fnsymbol{footnote}$}` and then doing `\def\@fnsymbol#1{{{^{\scriptstyle\@arabic{#1}}}\relax}}` is simply crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class does

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\mbox{$\fnsymbol{footnote}$}}
\def\@fnsymbol#1{{{^{\scriptstyle\@arabic{#1}}}\relax}}
```

which is simply crazy. Here's a couple of hacks, but they can give unexpected results elsewhere.

```
\documentclass{cambridge7A}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\textsuperscript{\@thefnmark}}
\long\def\@makefntext#1{\raggedright\@setpar{\@@par\@tempdima \hsize
 \advance\@tempdima-\@footindent
 \parshape \@ne \@footindent \@tempdima}\par
 \noindent \hbox to \z@{\hss\textsuperscript{\@thefnmark}\enskip}#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Suppose we introduce a footnote here\footnote{\label{myfootnote}And here's the note text!},
and then we later refer want to refer to the note, as fn.~\ref{myfootnote}.

Then the number in the latter cross-reference is superscripted,
when we of course will want a simple inline reference, like this: fn. 1.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks, I really appreciate it. This certainly seems to work (and without unexpected results elsewhere, in my book as it exists so far).